# Spring batch job should be executed only once after the spring integration poller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration

I wanted trigger spring batch only once when the files available in directory using spring integration poller.
Lets say suppose at a given point of time i have 5 files in watch directory trigger spring batch with all 5 files only once. Not for every individual file. Please help me.

Comment: Does this mean you want to run a single job with all files as parameter(s), and not a job per file? Are you using the [FileReadingMessageSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/file.html#directory-scanning-and-polling)? Please share your code to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is an out-of-the-box `ItemProcessor` in Spring Batch to handle a list of files. So, it sounds like you have some custom one or do something in your job to split that list and so on. Nevertheless there is no such a source in Spring Integration to get the whole list of files in the provided dir. You probably still need to come up with a custom one if you don't like to use a `FileReadingMessageSource` for a single file producing.

A simple way I see at the moment is to have a dummy `MessageSource` for the poller, e.g. producing just a static dir as a payload for next flow endpoint:

```
@InboundChannelAdapter("fileListChannel")
@Bean
Supplier<String> dirSource() {
    return () -> "myDir";
}
```

The `fileListChannel` consumer would be also a simple service-activator to take a file list from that dir:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "fileListChannel", outputChannel = "startJobChannel")
File[] obtainFileList(File dir) {
    return dir.listFiles();
}
```

Does it make sense to you?